# Sqlite using Python3 error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to insert some data into a sqlite database by following : -

```
param = '("593863695396044801","Ivan F. Siahaan","307783731","None","65","83","Thu Apr 30 19:45:13 +0000 2015","xyz")'

>>> conn.execute("INSERT INTO data "+param) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

I initialized connection to database as follows :-

```
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite

conn = sqlite.connect('dataStore')
```

What wrong I am doing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting your SQL syntax wrong; both the quoting and the `INSERT` statement syntax are incorrect.

SQLite doesn't support double quotes around string values, only single quotes. From the [SQLite keywords documenation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

> `'keyword'`       A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
>   `"keyword"`       A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.

You are using double quotes, but for string literals you need to use single quotes instead.

You are also missing the `VALUES` keyword; see the [`INSERT` statement documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html); the pattern is `INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (<value list>)`.

You really want to leave quoting to the database itself, however. Use SQL parameters here:

```
statement = "INSERT INTO data VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
params = (593863695396044801, "Ivan F. Siahaan", 307783731, None, 65, 83, "Thu Apr 30 19:45:13 +0000 2015", "xyz")
conn.execute(statement, params)
```

Note that this would also let you use the Python `None` singleton to insert a `NULL` in the database.

Comment: I modified param as param = "('593863695396044801','Ivan F. Siahaan','307783731','None','65','83','Thu Apr 30 19:45:13 +0000 2015','xyz')"
 But it still produces same error ..

Comment: @AkashRana: you are missing `VALUES` as well.

Comment: Strangely I can accept your answer only after 8 minutes .. :)